# using alias in Ext.data.store for model

Tags: extjs

Can any one help me on my issue?

I have created a model and set the alias name to that model and using the same alias name in `Ext.data.store` and set the model to the alias name and it doesn't work, but with complete name of model it works. Why?

```
Ext.define('lancet.asset.system.combobox.models.PathwayModel', { extend: 'lancet.def.system.model.Model', alias: 'widget.pathwaymodel', fields: [ { name: 'Id', type: 'string' }, { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }, { name: 'group', type: 'string' } ] });


Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { model: 'lancet.asset.system.combobox.models.PathwayModel',//it's work autoLoad: true }


Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{ model:'PathwayModel',//it doesn't work autoLoad:true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-model):

> Name of the Model associated with this store. The string is used as an
>   argument for [Ext.ModelManager.getModel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.ModelManager-method-getModel).

I expects a **name**, not an **alias** so thats the reason it works only with a name.

If you want to create a custom store that accepts the model as an alias you can do it using [`getNameByAlias()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.ClassManager-method-getNameByAlias) (but I guess you'd like to use a diffrent prefix and not `widget`).